# 'Model' object has no attribute 'loss_functions'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have completed a udacity nanodegree for NLP.  I used the udacity platform for the project, but I am now trying to use my own local machine to train models etc.

I've finally gotten my GPU/tensorflow issues worked out(I think), but I'm running into some problems that I believe are related to the versions of tensorflow that udacity was using.

I am currently using TensorFlow 2.2

Specifically, I am getting an error from a validation step the project uses to list the loss function.

```
def _test_model(model, input_shape, output_sequence_length, french_vocab_size):
    if isinstance(model, Sequential):
        model = model.model
        
    print(model.loss_functions)
```

When this is called I get the "'Model' object has no attribute 'loss_functions'" error.

The model is built with the below code.

```
def simple_model(input_shape, output_sequence_length, english_vocab_size, french_vocab_size):
    """
    Build and train a basic RNN on x and y
    :param input_shape: Tuple of input shape
    :param output_sequence_length: Length of output sequence
    :param english_vocab_size: Number of unique English words in the dataset
    :param french_vocab_size: Number of unique French words in the dataset
    :return: Keras model built, but not trained
    """
   
    # TODO: Build the layers
    
    learning_rate = 0.01
    
    #Config Model
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape[1:])
    hidden_layer = GRU(output_sequence_length, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
    outputs = TimeDistributed(Dense(french_vocab_size, activation='softmax'))(hidden_layer)
    
    #Create Model from parameters defined above
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    #loss_function = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
    loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
    model.compile(loss=loss_fn,optimizer=Adam(learning_rate),metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I am using the below libraries along the way

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.losses import sparse_categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow import keras
import collections


import helper
import numpy as np
import project_tests as tests

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential

from tensorflow.keras.layers import GRU, Input, Dense, TimeDistributed, Activation, RepeatVector, Bidirectional, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.losses import sparse_categorical_crossentropy
```

I can just comment out this check for the loss functions, but I would really like to understand what happened.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the API changed in Tensorflow 2, does the following work:

```
model.compiled_loss._get_loss_object(model.compiled_loss._losses).fn
```

Comment: Yes!  That works.  Was also about to find some information about this change as well(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38269).  This is not quite as simple to remember as "loss_functions" though.  But, it sounds like that it was never intended to be available anyway.